# How do I return a document with filtered sub-documents using Mongo.Driver.Linq with the Mongo C# driver 2.3?

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq, mongodb-.net-driver

Given the following, how do I return all the Foos that contain Bars that have TypeOfBar == "Big" *and* have the Foos' Bars be limited to only those Bars that have TypeOfBar == "Big" as well?

```
public class Foo
{
    public string _id { get; set; }
    public List<Bar> Bars { get; set; }
}

public class Bar
{
    public string _id { get; set; }
    public string TypeOfBar { get; set; }
}
```

I can easily get the first part (all Foos with Bars of a particular type):

```
var client = new MongoClient("myconnectionstring");
var db = client.GetDatabase("myDb");
var collection = db.GetCollection<Foo>("Foos");

var foos = collection.AsQueryable().Where(x => x.Bars.Any(b => b.TypeOfBar == "Big"));
```

However, I'm having a hard time figuring out how to also have the db return the Foos with a filtered list of Bars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to filter out only this Foos that have type "Big"  you should apply `ElemMatch` Projection:

```
var res = collection.Find(x => x.Bars.Any(b => b.TypeOfBar == "Big"))
    .Project(Builders<Foo>.Projection.ElemMatch(x=>x.Bars, b=>b.TypeOfBar == "Big"));
```

The problem you will have with it: Projection will return BSon.  Perhaps that is what you need and you could live with it, if not, you shuold deserialize Bson to your Foo class. Complete query i did look like:

```
var res = collection.Find(x => x.Bars.Any(b => b.TypeOfBar == "Big"))
    .Project(Builders<Foo>.Projection.ElemMatch(x=>x.Bars, b=>b.TypeOfBar == "Big"))
    .ToEnumerable()
    .Select(b=>BsonSerializer.Deserialize<Foo>(b))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: I think you've misunderstood what I was asking.  Yes, both of your examples return Foos that have Bars with TypeOfBar == "Big", however, they don't *also* filter the returned Foos' Bars to only those Bars with TypeOfBar == "Big".

Comment: So this works in the toy case above, where Foo only has an _id and a list of Bars, but if Foo has some additional properties, than the answer above does not work...the returned Foos only have a list of Bars, but none of their other properties are filled out. 

How can I return the Foos with a filtered list of Bars, as well as the other properties of Foo?